# how to make a long Figure Caption justified?

Tags: captions, justification

I can't seem to find the solution to make my caption justified.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{figure}
    \caption{The transitions for the monopolist firm's optimal product line strategy as either $\beta$, $\omega$ or $\alpha_n$ changes. In each panel, $c_v$ and $c_r$ vary between $0$ and $0.9$ within the vertical and horizontal axis, respectively; fixed parameters are $k=0.1$ and $\alpha_c=0.2$. From left-to-right in panel (a), the green variant's recycled content fraction increases: $\beta \in \{5\%, 50\%, 75\%\}$ (with $\alpha_n=0.2$ and $\omega=0.5$). From left-to-right in panel (b), the conventional consumer segment percentage increases: $\omega \in \{15\%, 50\%, 95\%\}$ (with $\alpha_n=0.2$ and $\beta=0.5$) and From left-to-right in panel (c), the naturalites' marginal utility from recycled content increases:  $\alpha_n \in \{5\%, 25\%, 55\%\}$ (with $\beta=\omega=0.5$).}
\end{figure}
```

Here is how it shows:

[image]

I have tried adding

```
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: Could you please add a minimal working example, or add more information to tell us what result you are getting and what effect do you want? By default the long caption should already be justified, if it is not, it's probably because you have changed the default setting somewhere -- in this case, let us know what you have done.

Comment: captions are justified by default in most document classes so hard to tell you what to change of you do not show why your captions are not justified. Note you should not put a font size in the caption, apart form logical objections to havig styling in the markup, it will mess up the list of figures as you probably don't want to force a different size there

Comment: You can add `\begingroup` before `\centering`, and `\endgroup` before the caption.

Answer (score 8):

Without a MWE, I can only assume what the cause is, but I think you have `\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}` loaded (because I encountered the same problem recently).
So, I'm assuming you are working with something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\captionsetup{%
    justification=justified,%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{The transitions for the monopolist firm's optimal product line strategy as either $\beta$, $\omega$ or $\alpha_n$ changes. In each panel, $c_v$ and $c_r$ vary between $0$ and $0.9$ within the vertical and horizontal axis, respectively; fixed parameters are $k=0.1$ and $\alpha_c=0.2$. From left-to-right in panel (a), the green variant's recycled content fraction increases: $\beta \in \{5\%, 50\%, 75\%\}$ (with $\alpha_n=0.2$ and $\omega=0.5$). From left-to-right in panel (b), the conventional consumer segment percentage increases: $\omega \in \{15\%, 50\%, 95\%\}$ (with $\alpha_n=0.2$ and $\beta=0.5$) and From left-to-right in panel (c), the naturalites' marginal utility from recycled content increases:  $\alpha_n \in \{5\%, 25\%, 55\%\}$ (with $\beta=\omega=0.5$).}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The solution to this is the (AFAIK undocumented) option `justification=Justified` with a capital J (or you could avoid the `newcommands` option).

```
...
\captionsetup{%
    justification=Justified,%
}
...
```

[image]

Again, without knowing what class/packages you are using, this is only a guess, but maybe this answer helps someone else with this rare problem.